# .numChildren() always returning 0

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I was following the [likes](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/child-count/functions/index.js) example

using their exact structure, but for a different purpose:

```
/functions-project-12345
    /db
        /1
            contacts_count: 0
            /contacts
                1: true
                2: true
                3: true
```

**contacts_count** gets created at the correct location, Although for some reason, **contacts_count** keeps returning 0

```
exports.contactsCount = functions.database.ref('/db/{userid}/contacts').onWrite(event => {
    return event.data.ref.parent.child('contacts_count').set(event.data.numChildren());
});
```

I have also tried setting the trigger at /db/{userid}/contacts/{id}, and after reading all the docs, still I can't seem to get it to return the correct count.

in fact, having the exact same structure as in the likes example:

```
/functions-project-12345
    /posts
        /key-123456
            likes_count: 32
            /likes 
                user123456: true
                user456789: true
                user786245: true
```

and running on the server:

```
exports.countlikes = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postid}/likes').onWrite(event => {
  return event.data.ref.parent.child('likes_count').set(event.data.numChildren());
});
```

still saves **0** into **likes_count**

is `event.data` in `event.data.numChildren()` a reference to the /db/{userid}/contacts node, right ?

Comment: Hi, I have the same result too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 04/13/17: The solution below only works if you can guarantee children nodes are only added (not deleted or changed) and does not handle the count node being deleted. For a more robust solution, check out the updated [child count example in the `firebase/functions-samples` repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count).**

I'm not sure exactly what is going wrong with your code (I just tested the example and it works for me), but a safer way to do this same thing is to use [transaction()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#transaction) instead of set(). Modifying your provided sample code, that would look like this:

```
exports. contactsCount = functions.database.ref('/db/{userid}/contacts')
  .onWrite(event => {
    var contactCountRef = event.data.ref.parent.child('contacts_count');
    return contactCountRef.transaction(function(currentCount) {
      return (currentCount || 0) + 1;
    });
  });
```

This code should work for you since it doesn't rely on whatever issue you are running into with `numChildren()` and it has the added benefit of being safe from race conditions that are present in the official sample. We are actually working to get the sample updated to properly use a transaction instead.